# Changing widget height - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a vetical seekBar in a RelativeLayout which is also inside other LinearLayout and all the layouts consist of a cell or view in a recyclerView. Anyway when I try to change the height of the seekbar using LayoutParams

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
seekBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I got a cast error stating that I cannot cast RelativeLayout to FrameLayout even if there is no FrameLayout present... I don't want to use Framelayout so I won't replace relativeLayout with frameLayout...

I have tried also lots of things like with no effect :

```
seekBar.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
seekBar.requestLayout()
```

I really appreciate it if someone can help me!

Comment: Could you please post your layout XML? Also It would be greate to know if  that layout is `included` or `merged` to another layout. Because of error  looks like `seekBar` is actually in FrameLayout - that is why I'm asking.

Comment: Thank you so much your comment made me realize that in fact the seekbar parent was not a relativeLayout and problem is fixed!